# modified Dominated convergence theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Dominated convergence theorem:
If for some random variable $Z$, we have that $|X_{n}|\leq |Z|$ for all $n$ and $\mathbb{E}[Z]<\infty$, then $X_{n}\stackrel{d}{\to}X$ implies that $\mathbb{E}[X_{n}] \to \mathbb{E}[X]$. This is well known.

I got stuck with the following "modification": assume, that instead of $|X_{n}|\leq |Z|$ we have the following:

$|X_{n}|\leq |Z_{n}|$, where $Z_{n}$ is a sequence s. t. $Z_{n}\stackrel{d}{\to}Z$, $\mathbb{E}[Z_{n}]\to \mathbb{E}[Z]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Z_{n}]=a<\infty$, THE SAME! for all $n$.

Is the statement about convergence of means true in this case?

I am thinking to introduce a new variable $Z_{max} = \max\{Z_{1}, Z_{2}, \dots, Z_{n}, \dots\}$, but I doubt that $\mathbb{E}[Z_{max}]<\infty$ in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the counter-example in my previous answer, let's modify the statement:

#### Claim 1: (Modified statement)

Suppose $X_n\rightarrow X$ in distribution, $Z_n\rightarrow Z$ in distribution, $E[Z_n]\rightarrow E[Z]<\infty$, and $|X_n|\leq Z_n$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. Then $E[X]$ is finite and $E[X_n]\rightarrow E[X]$.

Before proving this, it is useful to state and prove a lesser-known modification of the usual Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem:

#### Claim 2: (Modified LDC)

Suppose $f_n$ and $g_n$ are real-valued functions that satisfy $0\leq f_n(x)\leq g_n(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $f_n$ converges pointwise almost everywhere to a function $f$, $g_n$ converges pointwise almost everywhere to a function $g$, and $\int  g_n  \rightarrow \int g  < \infty$. Then $\int  f  < \infty$ and $\int  f_n  \rightarrow \int f$.

Proof of Claim 2: (almost the same as the standard LDC proof) We know by Fatou's lemma: 
$$ \int \liminf f_n \leq \liminf \int f_n  $$ 
The left-hand-side is $\int f$.  Hence: 
$$ \int f \leq \liminf \int f_n \quad (Eq 1) $$
It also easily follows that $\int f < \infty$.

On the other hand, applying Fatou to the nonnegative functions $g_n-f_n$ gives: 
$$  \underbrace{\int \liminf (g_n-f_n)}_{\int g - \int f } \leq \underbrace{
\liminf\int (g_n-f_n)}_{\int g - \limsup \int f_n} $$
Since $\int g$ is finite we get 
$$\limsup \int f_n \leq \int f $$
Combining this with equation (1) gives: 
$$ \int f \leq \liminf \int f_n \leq \limsup \int f_n \leq \int f $$ 
$\Box$

#### Derivation of Claim 1:

It suffices to assume $X_n\geq 0$ for all $n$ (else, we can write $X_n=X_n^+ - X_n^-$ and repeat the argument on the positive and negative parts). Define: 
\begin{align}
f_n(x) &= P[X_n>x]\\
f(x) &= P[X>x]\\
g_n(x) &= P[Z_n>x]\\
g(x) &=P[Z>x]
\end{align}
We know that $0\leq f_n(x) \leq g_n(x)$ for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ and all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. We also know that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise almost everywhere, and $g_n$ converges to $g$ pointwise almost everywhere. We also know that:
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} g_n(x)dx = E[Z_n]\\
\int_0^{\infty} f_n(x)dx = E[X_n]\\
\int_0^{\infty} g(x)dx = E[Z] < \infty \\
\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx = E[X]
\end{align}
Finally, we know that $\int_0^{\infty} g_n(x)dx\rightarrow \int_0^{\infty} g(x)dx$. It follows by Claim 2 that $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx< \infty$ and $\int_0^{\infty} f_n(x)dx \rightarrow \int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx$.  That is, $E[X_n]\rightarrow E[X]$. $\Box$

Comment: A minor adjustment of the proof of Claim 2 gives the following more general modified LDC statement:  If $f_n, g_n$ are functions that satisfy $|f_n|\leq g_n$ for all $n$, $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise almost everywhere, $g_n\rightarrow g$ pointwise almost everywhere, and $\int g_n \rightarrow \int g < \infty$, then $\int f$ is finite and $\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$.  This is nice because it says that we can interchange the limit and integral whenever the functions $f_n$ have magnitudes that are bounded by some other functions $g_n$ for which we can interchange the limit and integral.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is true under a minor modification, but it is not true as stated: For $n \in \{1, 2, 3, …\}$ define $Z_n$ by: 
$$ Z_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
n &\mbox{ with prob $1/(2n)$} \\
-n &\mbox{with prob $1/(2n)$} \\
0  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
Then $Z_n\rightarrow 0$ in distribution and $E[Z_n]=0$ for all $n$.  Define $X_n=|Z_n|$ for all $n$.  Then $X_n\rightarrow 0$ in distribution, but $E[X_n]=1$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution:

Let $Z_{n}>0$.

Since $Z_{n}$ is a sequence s. t. $Z_{n}\stackrel{d}{\to}Z$, $\mathbb{E}[Z_{n}]\to \mathbb{E}[Z]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Z_{n}]=a<\infty$, then $Z_{n}$ is asymptotically uniformly integrable.

Next, we can show, that, since $X_{n}\leq Z_{n}$, and, let's say that $X_{n}\geq 0$, then $X_{n}$ is also asymptotically uniformly integrable. 
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_{n}\mathbb{I}\{X_{n}>M\}]\leq \mathbb{E}[Z_{n}\mathbb{I}\{X_{n}>M\}]\leq\mathbb{E}[Z_{n}\mathbb{I}\{Z_{n}>M\}],
$$
so that
$$
\limsup \mathbb{E}[X_{n}\mathbb{I}\{X_{n}>M\}] \leq \limsup\mathbb{E}[Z_{n}\mathbb{I}\{Z_{n}>M\}]\to 0,
$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Then, we have done.

Comment: It is unusual to ask a question and then ignore the person who answers.  I gave two answers, the first shows your original conjecture is wrong.  The second makes a necessary modification and then proves a stronger statement that does not need the assumption $E[Z_n]=a$ for all $n$.  I observe that, 7 hours later, you have ignored both and have provided your own answer.  That answer does not make sense because: (i) It avoids the fact that the original statement was wrong, (ii) It introduces an unknown quantity $M$ and incorrectly suggests $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[Z_n1\{Z_n>M\}]=0$.

Comment: More care would need to be taken to show that for a given $\epsilon>0$, there is an $M$ such that $E[Z_n1\{Z_n>M\}]\leq \epsilon$ for all sufficiently large $n$.  It does not follow from the fact that $Z_n\geq 0$ and $E[Z_n]=a$ for all $n$, more properties would need to be used.

Comment: First, sorry, that you think I ignored you, cause I didn't. Thank you very much for your effort. Second, what do u meant unknown quantity? This is a definition of Uniform Integrability (UI), isnt't it? See, for example, Theorem 2.20 in van der Vaart. If we have convergence in distribution, then we have convergence of means IFF sequence is UI. 

So, $Z_{n}$ is UI. After that I have proved that $X_{n}$ is UI.What is wrong now? 

The modification was $|X_{n}| \leq Z_{n}$ for all $n, wasn't it? 

Once again, I am sorry if it was impolite...

Comment: Your $M$ is an "unknown quantity" since it was never defined, and its relationship to $n$ was not specified.  If $M$ is a real number that does not depend on $n$, then you can show $Z_n1\{Z_n>M\}$ converges in distribution to $Z1\{Z>M\}$ and so (since $Z_n$ itself provides the bounding variable for use in my claim 1 above) $E[Z_n1\{Z_n>M\}]\rightarrow E[Z1\{Z>M\}]$, and this is typically nonzero, contradicting your claim that this converges to 0.  If you want $M$ to be related to $n$, like $M_n$, then you might be able to show $E[Z_n1\{Z_n>M_n\}]\rightarrow 0$ under some additional properties.

Comment: I am guessing that your Theorem 2.20 in the book you have (I do not have) is proven similar to how I prove claim 1, by using the fact $E[X]=\int_0^{\infty} P[X>t]dt$ for $X\geq 0$, since the result you state would also follow by claim 1.  Anyway, my proof uses this together with Fatou.

Comment: Dear @Michael, 

Yes, $M$ is a real number. The theorem I am referring to says: Let $f: R^{k} \to R$ be measurable and continuous at every point in a set
C. Let $Z_{n} \stackrel{d}{\to} Z$, where $Z$ takes its values in C. Then $\mathbb{E}[f(Z_{n})]\to\mathbb{E}[f(Z)]$ if and only if the
sequence of random variables $f(Z_{n})$ is asymptotically uniformly integrable.

Comment: The thm 2.20 that you refer to can indeed be used to prove a modified conjecture.  If you intended to prove the modified conjecture using thm 2.20, the residual mistakes in your answer might be viewed as minor typos (yet you have not acknowledged or fixed anything).   It is still not clear if you agree with my previous observations, namely: (i) The original conjecture is false [see my counter-example], (ii) We can have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[Z_n 1\{Z_n>M\}]>0$ for all $M$. If you really wanted $\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E[Z_n 1\{Z_n>M\}]=0$, that would be fine.

Comment: Of course, the way you state Theorem 2.20 is also false, since we require $f$ to be a nonnegative function (or at least lower-bounded).  My counter-example is again a counter-example to your statement of Theorem 2.20, treating $f(Z_n)=Z_n$. Those $Z_n$ values satisfy $E[Z_n]\rightarrow 0$ and $Z_n$ goes to 0 in distribution, yet not asymptotically UI since $\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E[|Z_n|1\{|Z_n|>M\}]=1$.